# Implementing Broadcast receivers within asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I am pretty new to Android. I am working on this project which displays a list of applications and it's details in a listview. I get the list of applications as a JsonArray from a server. I use a service to retrieve the JsonArray and a LocalBroadcastManager to broadcast it to the MainActivity. Everything works fine for me. But it takes a couple of seconds to get the data into my mainacitvity. This causes my app to display just a blank screen. Therefore I thought to add a Progress Dialogbox to display till I get the data from the service. I found an example to display Progress dialog box using Asynctask (link: [How to use progress dialog in AsyncTask in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426356/how-to-use-progress-dialog-in-asynctask-in-android)). But my problem is that, I don't know how to implement my Broascast receiver method inside the Asyntask DoInBackground method.  I searched for some answers but couldn't find any.

I will really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this, or suggest me an alternate method to do this. Thanks in Advance

**My code:**

this is the method in the service class that, I'm using to broadcast the JSONArray to the mainActivity

```
private void broadcastMessage(String message, String extraType) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent("my-event");
    if (message != null){
        intent.putExtra(extraType, message);
    }
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

message here contains my JSONArray as a String.

Here is the code I'm using in the mainActivity to get the data:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
              new IntentFilter("my-event"));
```

Where mMessagerReceiver is an object of BroadcastReceiver.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        results = intent.getStringExtra("JSONArray");
        Log.e("receiver", "got your message");
    }
};
```

This code works fine with me.. But now I want the broascastReceiver to be within my asynctask. Is it possible to do?

Comment: post your code also.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use google Volly  for your web service  call , so that you can call the api from your activity and get the result there. also easy to handle progress Dialog Json to gson etc.

Comment: check:http://blog.aimanbaharum.com/2014/02/android-development-5-using-volley-and.html
http://www.michenux.net/android-volley-and-gson-tutorial-797.html
https://gist.github.com/ficusk/5474673
http://www.piwai.info/android-string-placeholders/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it was a little bit complicated to integrate your suggestion with What i already did.